# Windows 8, Diskpart, "The command you selected is not available with this version of Windows"

Tags: windows-8, mirroring, diskpart

Windows 8, not Pro or Enterprise.

I want to mirror a volume.  I run Diskpart, and type:

```
  select volume 1
  add disk 1
```

and this appears:

```
  The command you selected is not available with this version of Windows.
```

Any information that I've found about Diskpart suggests that it works in all editions of recent versions of Windows.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mirroring is not available in home versions of Windows, even through diskpart

Comment: Thank you.  I found dozens of web sites providing helpful information about mirroring disks (including Microsoft's), but not one that mentioned this relevant detail.